# ASP: Passing value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Im trying to pass a value bounded with a button in form1.aspx to form2.aspx

form1.aspx:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" CommandArgument = '<%#Eval("Parking_ID")%>' />
```

the button is within a repeater which is bounded to a datasource that `Select * From [Parking]`

Each button in the repeater should have a unique `parking_Id` based on `CommandArgument`.

In form1.aspx.vb:

```
Protected Sub repeater1_ItemCommand(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterCommandEventArgs) Handles repeater1.ItemCommand
        Dim value As Int32 = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)
        Response.Redirect("form2.aspx?id=" & value)
        Session("field4") = value
```

In Form2.aspx.vb:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
Dim field4 As String = CType(Session.Item("field4"), String)
Parking_ID1.Text = field4
```

But the `Parking_ID1.text Label` is not showing any values.

Any help would be appreciated

Regards

Comment: Why don't you just use the "id" querystring parameter in Form2? Currently you are passing the value as a querystring parameter as well as storing it in the session, which seems redundant.

Comment: Response.Redirect("form2.aspx?id=" & value,True)

Comment: @Andres Fjeldstad Thanks, Tried both suggestions and it is still not passing.

Comment: @Govind KamalaPrakash Malviya it did not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're redirecting before you set the session.

Also, you can more easily pickup the value in Form2.aspx.vb by just doing:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
Dim field4 As String = Request.Querystring("id")
Parking_ID1.Text = field4
```

You'll have to forgive my VB.net syntax, long time since I used it, but the concept should work for you.

Extending the answer based upon a request from the poster:

Should you wish to pass multiple parameters across, there are a few ways of doing it, though your model is the right basis for this:

```
Protected Sub repeater1_ItemCommand(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterCommandEventArgs) Handles repeater1.ItemCommand
    Dim value As Int32 = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)
    Dim dataItem as YourStronglyTypedItem = e.Item.DataItem as YourStronglyTypedItem // c# there - sorry
    Session("field4") = dataItem.Property1
    Session("field5") = dataItem.Property2 // etc.
    Response.Redirect("form2.aspx?Parking_ID=" & value & "&OtherProperty=" & dataItem.Property2)
```

The syntax isn't ideal (and some of it is in c#, sorry!), but essentially, if you can grab the bound data item (through e.Item.DataItem) and cast it to whatever object you bound in the first place then you can grab as many properties from it as you like.

So say you databound List to it.  e.Item.DataItem cast to Widget will give you the values of that particular widget, then you can either set multiple session values (or indeed just put the whole widget into session), or you can pass multiple query string parameters as I have done above.

hope that helps?

Comment: @Terry_Brown thanks terry. I am afraid that no values are being passed still the same

Comment: Hi Humam - if you put a breakpoint inside your repeater1_ItemCommand block, does e.CommandArgument have something in it?  Also, on redirect does it say: Form2.aspx?id=  or Form2.aspx?id=<number here> ?

Comment: @Terry_Brown It worked I put the database field name wrong. it is supposed to be `Form2.aspx?Parking_ID=` thanks aloot !!

Comment: glad to help, and glad my VB.net syntax didn't make me look a total noob! lol

Comment: @Terry_Brown what if i want to pass other values as well, will it work to use the same procedure in my question ?

Comment: it will indeed - I'll extend my answer above

Comment: @Terry_Brown what do u mean by this `YourStronglyTypedItem`? It seems a bit complicated? Can I bind multiple values to the button such as `<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" CommandArgument = '<%#Eval("Parking_ID")%>', '<%#Eval("Parking_ID")%>' />` but I think the problem will be in the `ItemCommand` since e which is the event is repeated several times and wont know which value to pick ??

Comment: you can't easily do that unfortunately no, but by YourStronglyTypedItem, I mean if you bound a list to your repeater like:  `List<Product>` then your strongly typed item would be a `Product` - e.Item.DataItem should give you back that `Product` so that you can do whatever you want with it

Comment: @Terry_Brown I am trying with it but it is not working. Could you provide me with an example coz i am a bit confused my repeater code is: `<asp:Repeater ID="repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnItemDataBound="repeater1_ItemDataBound">
 <ItemTemplate>
 <li>
  <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" "><%#Eval("Parking_Name")%> </asp:Label></div>         
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" CommandArgument = '<%#Eval("Parking_ID")%>' />
</li>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>` Now button is having the parking_Id, I need the parking_Name as well ???

Comment: can you show me what you have in your SqlDataSource1 please humam?

Comment: @Terry_Brown `Select * From [Parking] WHERE [ParkingStartTime] <> @StartTime1 AND [ParkingStartTime] > @StartTime1 AND ParkingStartTime > @EndTime1 OR ParkingEndTime < @StartTime1 AND ParkingStartTime < @EndTime1 OR ParkingStartTime is NULL OR ParkingEndTime IS NULL` `@StartDate` is a calender control `@StartTime` and `@EndTime` are ComboBoxes

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the correct syntax below.
Dim field4 As String = Request.QueryString["id"]